# Verilog testbench error! not compiling

Tags: verilog

```
module top;

reg CLOCK=1'b0;

reg CLEAR = 1'b1;

wire [2:0]Q;


$monitor($time, "COUNT Q = %b CLEAR = %b" , Q[3:0],CLEAR);

john_counter a1 (Q,CLOCK,CLEAR);

forever

begin

  #1 CLOCK=~CLOCK;

end

begin

#20 CLEAR = 1'b0;

#6 CLEAR = 1'b1;

end

begin

#40 $finish;

end

endmodule
```

I wrote this verilog test bench for johnson counter module..
please tell me the errors in this.

I am getting
ERROR: sim2.vparse error before token '$monitor'.

"$monitor" syntax error, unexpected SYSTEM_TASK_FUNC.

ERROR: sim2.v: parse error before token '#'.

"#" syntax error, unexpected '#'.

ERROR: sim2.v(line 19): parse error before token '#'.

"#" syntax error, unexpected '#'.

ERROR: sim2.v(line 24): parse error before token '#'.

"#" syntax error, unexpected '#'.

> > 1 source file(s) fail to parse

Comment: Please markup your code as code and indent it.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the 'initial' keywords.  You want your clock, reset, and test processes to all run concurrently.

```
module top;

reg CLOCK = 1'b0;
reg CLEAR = 1'b1;
wire [2:0] Q;

john_counter a1 (Q,CLOCK,CLEAR);

// clock process
initial begin
  forever begin
    #1 CLOCK=~CLOCK;
  end
end

// reset process
initial begin
  #20 CLEAR = 1'b0;
  #6 CLEAR = 1'b1;
end

// test process
initial begin
  $monitor("%g COUNT Q = %b CLEAR = %b" , $time, Q, CLEAR);

  #40 $finish;
end

endmodule
```

Also, your $monitor needs to be called from a process.

Comment: when I am using initial keyword... it is ignored by my compiler. Please tell me the alternatives.

Comment: Which simulator are you using?  The "initial" keyword is a fundamental part of the Verilog language and is supported by all of the major Verilog simulators.

Comment: my senior told me that this code is not synthesizable..how to make it that?